# Specify date only sorting on a timestamp field in spring mongo

Tags: mongodb, sorting, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to sort my records based on multiple fields. But, the records are getting sorted only by the first sort criteria. If I use the sort properties separately it's working fine.

Expected result is first it needs to get sorted by created date in descending order then it should get sorted by users count in descending order.

Below are my list of records, expected result should be in the order of record 3 record 2 and record 1. First it should get sorted by createdDate and then by users count.

```
// record 1
{
 "_id": "a46asgasyas" 
 "content": "sample data set 1",
 "userscount": 0,
 "createdDate": ISODate("2016-12-11T13:45:53.991Z")
},
// record 2
{
 "_id": "a46asgasyas" 
 "content": "sample data set 2",
 "userscount": 0,
 "createdDate": ISODate("2016-12-17T13:45:53.991Z")
},
// record 3
{
 "_id": "a46asgasyas" 
 "content": "sample data set 3",
 "userscount": 2,
 "createdDate": ISODate("2016-12-15T13:45:53.991Z")
}
```

Below are the code that I have tried,

```
**Code snippet 1:**
new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdDate"),
new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "userscount"));

**Code snippet 2:**
new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdDate").and(,
new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "userscount")));
```

Both code are sorting only based on the first criteria. Can some one help me why is the code not working with both sort criteria's?

Comment: Apart from typo (`users` should be `userscount`) the query will work fine. Query sorts first by the createdDate field in desc order, and then within each createdDate sort by userscount field in desc order.

Comment: @Veeram Yeah but it's not working

Comment: It works fine. You just don't have enough documents. Consider  additional document `{
 "userscount": 1,
 "createdDate": ISODate("2016-12-11T13:45:53.991Z")
}`  now you should see something like `{
 "userscount": 1,
 "createdDate": ISODate("2016-12-11T13:45:53.991Z")
}, {
 "userscount": 0,
 "createdDate": ISODate("2016-12-11T13:45:53.991Z")
}`. Notice how they are sorted by userscount desc.

Comment: No same result only,it not working

Comment: I've verified both using spring and mongodb. It works. Can you explain how are you verifying ?

Comment: I am using the second code snippet mentioned in my question. I have records for 11th (user count - 4) , 12th (user count - 0) ,13th (user count - 0) ,15th (user count - 0) ,15th (user count - 2). Now when its sorted date in desc order result should be 15th (user count - 0) ,15th (user count - 2) ,13th (user count - 4) , 12th (user count - 0) ,11th (user count - 0). Again after sorting with user count result should be 13th (user count - 4) ,15th (user count - 2) ,15th (user count - 0) ,12th (user count - 0) ,11th (user count - 0).  I am able to get sorted by date but not by the userscount.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161383/discussion-between-karthik-and-veeram).